# Set variables in regex with zero-or-one matching

Tags: regex, tcl

I have to divide ip-address and port and use this code

```
set str 192.168.1.1:44
set port 23
regexp {(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d+)?} $str all ip port
puts $ip
puts $port
```

And it works perfectly. But if use *$str* without port (ex. 192.168.1.1), none of variables were set and TCL returns an error.

```
can't read "ip": no such variable
```

Regex still matches "192.168.1.1" with no port (I checked it with "if" statement), with no port, but why doesn't it return variables? I expected $all and $ip.

Comment: It should be `(:\d+)?`..you need to make `colon` optional

Answer (score 2):

```
set str 192.168.1.1:44
lassign [split $str :] ip port
if {$port eq ""} {
    set port 23
}
puts $ip
puts $port
```

If you need to verify that the `$ip` string is a valid IP address, it's better to use the `ip` package than a regular expression (the regular expression you use will accept a lot of invalid IP addresses).

Note that you are going to have a lot of problems with IPv6 addresses.

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [ip](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html) package

Comment: The ip package probably uses regular expressions. But it uses the right ones that have been debugged against a bunch of real nasty test cases.

Comment: @DonalFellows: there are three invocations of regexp in the package, and they are very sensibly limited in scope. There is nothing wrong with regular expressions, but I find they're very often used sloppily and naively.

Answer (score 1):

You should be making colon optional and capturing regex in different group.

**Regex:** `^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::?(\d+))?$`

**Explanation:**

- IP Address is captured in first group.
- Optional port number is captured in second group. `:` is part of non-capturing group so it's not captured in second group.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK9qZ6/2)**

Comment: Thanks... I'm really confused. It solves, of course. My checking If-statement has colon included in brackets, so it made me ask a question :(

Comment: Technically, this would match an IP with trailing colon but no port — "192.168.1.1:".

Comment: @bipll: Updated my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyNwe: You were checking for optional port number but `:` was still intact. You need to make it optional at the same time not capture it in group.

Comment: @noob, while your answer is correct, your online demo is using pcre not Tcl regexes: they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
sharad@ss:~$ cat my.tcl 
proc foo {str} {
    regexp {(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(:(\d+))?} $str all ip tmp port
    puts ip=$ip,port=$port
}
foo 192.168.1.1:44
foo 192.168.1.1
sharad@ss:~$ 


Output:
sharad@ss:~$ tclsh my.tcl 
ip=192.168.1.1,port=44
ip=192.168.1.1,port=
sharad@ss:~$
```